# Override the method index_html of a custom content type

Tags: python, plone

I've a custom contentype. I need to override the base view of this objects only when is a anonymous user:

```
class Imagesblock(folder.ATFolder):
.......
 def index_html(self):
    """ use the parent view """

    portal_state = getMultiAdapter((self, self.REQUEST), name="plone_portal_state")
    if portal_state.anonymous()==True:
        response = self.REQUEST.response
        url = self.aq_parent.absolute_url()
        return response.redirect(url, status=303)
    else:
        return super(Imagesblock).index_html()
```

I supposed to use the index_html of the super class, but I obtain an error:

> AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'index_html'

Any suggestions?
Vito

Comment: super(Imagesblock, `self`).index_html()?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the method `index_html()` from the superclass, you should call it with

```
folder.ATFolder.index_html(self)
```

assuming `folder.ATFolder` is the name of the superclass.

**Edit:**

As @Mathias mentioned, you also could call it as:

```
super(Imagesblock, self).index_html()
```

Comment: I don't think so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-and-init-methods

The problem is in the comment from @mathias: you must provide also "self" until you are on Python 3.0

Comment: And I don't really know why the downvotes? The way I mentioned doesn't work? It works for me.

Comment: The downvotes are because you said something which simply isn't true, which is that `super` calls the constructor.

Comment: @DanielRoseman you are right, it was a confusion between languages, very early here. Edited.